# Raspberry Pi have ONE IP Address

Tags: wifi, internet

I am trying to figure out how to make my Raspberry Pi 2 B only have one IP address no matter whether it is connected by cable or over a USB WiFi dongle. When I connect the cable I get a different IP from the USB. This is a problem because I am moving my Pi around connecting it to different cables and then the dongle around my house. I am accessing it over SSH so I can't just hostname -I and find the IP. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You want to use a **static IP address**, if your router will let you.  Exactly how to do this may depend a little on what OS distribution you are using.

Comment: Adding to @goldilocks... In your router setup it might be called "DHCP reservation" or similar, even otherwise lousy  routers usually have it anymore.  Reservations are keyed to the MAC address which is likely different on wired vs wifi, hopefully the router will allow you to enter multiple MAC addresses all pointed to the same IP.  If that's not possible you will have to configure a static ip on the pi, and likewise with the same IP for wifi or wired connection.